# Find the smallest real number $M$ for which $\{a\} + \{b\} + \{c\} ≤ M$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, fractions, rational-numbers

This is a problem from an Ukrainian math competition which was held on 28 January 2024.

Find the smallest real number $M$ for which

$$\{a\} + \{b\} + \{c\} ≤ M$$

for any positive real numbers $a, b, c$ such that

$$abc=2024$$

where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$, for example: $$\{3.14\} = 0.14$$

I'm assuming the inequality of harmonic, geometric, arithmetic and quadratic means could be used to solve this, but have no idea how to actually apply it. Having all the means

$$x_{harmon}≤x_{geom}≤x_{arithm}≤x_{quadr}$$

which, for positive real numbers a, b and c is

$$\frac{3}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}}≤\sqrt[3]{abc}≤\frac{a + b + c}{3}≤\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}}$$

we can get (from the last inequality) to

$$\{a\} + \{b\} + \{c\} ≤ \sqrt{3(a^2+b^2+c^2)} - ([a]+[b]+[c])$$

where $[a] = a - \{a\}$ is a whole part of a number. We now have sum of those three fractions separated on the left, but I'm not sure what can be done further from this point.

There is an suggested answer for this problem. It's $2 + (2024/2025)$ which is approximately $2.99950....$ But what is the logic behind it and is it even correct - I'm not sure.

Comment: I have edited your post to include the standard notation for fractional part.  You may roll back the edit if you prefer the other notation.  Some people use frac$(x)$ and $\{x\}$ slightly differently, but these differences only arise for $x<0$.

Comment: Please edit your post to show your efforts.  I gather that $M$ is meant to be a function of $n$?  Is $n$ a natural number or just any positive real?  Have you solved this for any value of $n$?

Comment: Sry for that, I thought that it's possible to find the general answer for any natural n, yeah, but will be grateful for any help, for example lets assume n = 2024

Comment: Well, what have you tried?  Is there any reason to imagine the answer is $<3$?  I mean $(a,b,c)=(12.99,12.99,11.99477777)$ comes very close to $3$.

Comment: I'm aware that sum of 3 fractional parts will be less then 3, but it will probably be even less if we apply the rule of abc=2024

Comment: @lulu Thx for edits by the way, for some reason standard notation was not showing for me in preview, so I ended up with frac().

Comment: You probably left the \ mark out.  you need to write \{a\} to get $\{a\}$.

Comment: I was using escape characters, yeah, maybe was just a visual bug, idk.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of analysis and least upper bound? Obviously $\{a\}+ \{b\}+\{c\}<3$ but can it get as close as we like to $3$? Show that for any value $M < 3$ that we can find $a,b,c$ so that $M < \{a\}+ \{b\}+\{c\}<3$?  If so we have to conclude the number being asked for must be $3$ because 1) $\{a\}+ \{b\}+\{c\}\le3$ and 2) for any number *less* than $3$, we can find $M< \{a\}+ \{b\}+\{c\}$.

Comment: I have to say I don't see why the other commenters are suggesting that the answer is $3$. It seems to me that the answer must be less than $3$, roughly because "if $\{a\} + \{b\} + \{c\}$ is very very close to $3$, then the integer $\lceil a \rceil \lceil b \rceil \lceil c \rceil$ must be very very close to $2024$, while being strictly larger, which is absurd". In some rough work I think I can use this to show that $M \le 2.999999756135028$, for example. Finding $M$ itself doesn't seem totally straightforward though. I'd guess that having the ceils multiply to $2025$ would get you close.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen See lulu's example, we have $ \lceil a \rceil \ldots = 2028$, which isn't too absurd (to me) $\quad$     Agree with you that we likely can find an upper bound that is < 3. It's not immediately clear to me if we can get to a maximum/lub without tedious case checking.

Comment: Where does the problem come from? The use of $n=2024$ suggests a recent or ongoing competition.

Comment: It's a problem from a recent math competition held in January 2024, yeah.

Comment: There is an suggested answer for this problem. It's 2 + (2024/2025) which is approximately ~2.99950.... But what is the logic behind it and even is it correct - I'm not sure.

Comment: What is the name, date, and place of the competition? That information should be included in your post to provide some context for the problem. Also, you should show some of what you tried. Please edit your post accordingly.

Comment: Please provide the background of the competition, especially proof that it has ended. Some contest questions were closed and hidden recently without publicly available information. ["Contest problem" policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16775/89922).

Comment: Ty for all the suggestions! I've edited post with some of my thoughts on what can be done to help solve this problem. I've also added some information about this competition, not really sure what I can provide as a proof, but there is some information about it on the web: https://ippo.dn.ua/novyny-afisha/novyny/2024/vidbuvsya-iii-etap-vseukrajinskikh-uchnivskikh-olimpiad-z-matematiki-ta-trudovogo-navchannya-tekhnologij

Comment: @sleexed was the competition a numeric answer type or a subjective type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As D S observes, one can see that $M \ge 2 + \frac{2024}{2025}$ by taking any
integers $n, m$ with $nm = 2025$ and looking at the limit of
$(a, b, c) = (n - \epsilon, m - \epsilon, \frac{2024}{(n - \epsilon)(m - \epsilon)})$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

This example, along with my comment about the fact that near-optimal triples
tend to be "a bit less than a triple of integers multiplying to an integer close
to $2024$", already sort of suggests why this might be optimal. The idea is that
among triples $(a, b, c)$ with $\lceil a \rceil = n$, $\lceil b \rceil = m$
and $\lceil c \rceil = k$, the best you  can do is
$\{a\} + \{b\} + \{c\} \le 2 + \frac{2024}{mnk}$, with an example like in the first
paragraph. Once we've shown that, it's clear that the largest $M$ we can hope
for is given by making $mnk$ as small as possible, and hence taking $mnk$ to be
$2025$.

To prove this fact, we exactly need to prove the following:

**Lemma.** If $A, B, C \ge 0$ and $x, y, z \in [0, 1]$, then
\begin{equation*}
x + y + z \le 2 + \frac{(A + x)(B + y)(C + z)}{(A + 1)(B + 1)(C + 1)}
\end{equation*}

**Proof.** Fix $A, B, C$, and consider the function
\begin{equation*}
f(x, y, z) = -(x + y + z) + 2 + \frac{(A + x)(B + y)(C + z)}{(A + 1)(B + 1)(C + 1)}
\end{equation*}
We would like to show that $f(x, y, z) \ge 0$ for $x, y, z \in [0, 1]$.
We'll do this by minimising $f$.
Observe that $f$ is actually decreasing in each of its arguments.
(eg if $x_1 \le x_2$, then $f(x_1, y, z) \ge f(x_2, y, z)$, and so on - the
point being that with two arguments fixed, $f$ is a linear function with
non-positive gradient).
So $f$ is minimised when $(x, y, z) = (1, 1, 1)$.
But $f(1, 1, 1) = 0$. Hence $f(x, y, z) \ge 0$, and we are done.

(To apply this lemma, take
$A = \lfloor a \rfloor, B = \lfloor b \rfloor, C = \lfloor c \rfloor$
and $x = \{a\}, y = \{b\}, z = \{c\}$).

I have been a little bit loose with floors and ceilings here, but that is fine,
because if any of $a, b, c$ is an integer then of course
$\{a\} + \{b\} + \{c\} \le 2$, so that case isn't even worth thinking about.

Comment: I think this was the expected answer, as the participants obviously couldn't use a program or a calculator to guess the configuration. (+1)

Comment: Thanks for your effort, amazing work!

Answer (score 2):

**Partial Answer:**

The equality case is achieved when $a = 2025-(0.1)^n$, $b = 1-(0.1)^n$, $c = 2024/(ab)$ and $n \to \infty$, i.e, $(2024.999999\ldots, 0.999999\ldots, 0.99950\ldots)$.

If we set $a = 2025-(0.1)^n$, $b = 1-(0.1)^n$ for some $n$, then first we observe that $n=1,2,3$ does not give good solutions. Taking derivative of
$$f(x) = \frac{2024}{2025-2026(0.1)^x+(0.1)^{2x}}+2-2(0.1)^x$$we get
$$f'(x) = 2\ln(10)(0.1)^x-\frac{2024\left(2026\ln(10)(0.1)^x - 2\ln(10)(0.1)^{2x}\right)}{(2025-2026(0.1)^x+(0.1)^{2x})^2}$$
It is not hard to see that it is positive for $x\ge 4$ (in fact, it is positive after $x=1$, as seen from its graph). Also, the fraction in $f$ is less than $1$ for $x\ge4$.

Then, we can take limit to infinity to get the desired value of $\boxed{2+2024/2025}$.
I am still working to show this is the optimal case.

Comment: By a computer program, I was able to observe that this is an optimal configuration, but no mathematical proof yet...